# What is the size of different mouse brain cells?

Tags: brain, mouse

I am trying to isolate microglia from the adult mouse brain. I wondered if I would get pure microglia culture if, after homogenization, I filtered cell suspension through a 70um filter. But I could not find information about the sizes of different brain cell sizes.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers (with citations), what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Answer (score 1):

*In situ*, cortical neurons have soma commonly in the range of 10-20 um (see for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramidal_cell); it doesn't much matter if you talk of mice or any other mammal.

I'd recommend reading methods sections in papers that try to do something similar to what you want, rather than trying to invent a method from the bottom up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is I got a protocol for microglia isolation in my lab, and they told me that it works fine. However, it doesn't work for me so well, so I'm trying to make slight changes to adapt this protocol to work better.

Comment: @Monika1223 It can be really frustrating when people ask about just part of their problem pertaining to their narrow solution without context. StackOverflow has called it the XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/401068